# Вопрос по регулярным выражениям, могу ли получить данные в нужном виде?

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть регулярное выражение такого вида:

```
data = re.findall(r'(<pre.+?>.+?</pre>)|(<a.+?>.+?</a>)', text, flags=re.S)
```

И возвращается результат мне в таком виде:

```
# Это часть результата
('', '<a href="https://pythonprogramming.net/convolutional-neural-network-kats-vs-dogs-machine-learning-tutorial/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">https://pythonprogramming.net/convolutional-neural-network-kats-vs-dogs-machine-learning-tutorial/</a>')
```

Могу ли я не получать результат в виде кортежа с дополнительным элементом?

Answer (score 2):

Просто надо не использовать захватываемые группы. https://ideone.com/JhMJmp

```
import re

text = input()

data = re.findall(r'(<pre.+?>.+?</pre>)|(<a.+?>.+?</a>)', text, flags=re.S)
print(data)

data = re.findall(r'<pre.+?>.+?</pre>|<a.+?>.+?</a>', text, flags=re.S)
print(data)

data = re.findall(r'(?:<pre.+?>.+?</pre>)|(?:<a.+?>.+?</a>)', text, flags=re.S)
print(data)

data = re.findall(r'(<(pre|a)\b.+?>.+?</\2>)', text, flags=re.S)
print(data)

data = re.findall(r'<(?:pre|a)\b.+?>.+?</(?:pre|a)>', text, flags=re.S)
print(data)
```

```
<pre class="p">code</pre><span class="s">smth</span><a href="/">link</a>
```

```js
[('<pre class="p">code</pre>', ''), ('', '<a href="/">link</a>')]
['<pre class="p">code</pre>', '<a href="/">link</a>']
['<pre class="p">code</pre>', '<a href="/">link</a>']
[('<pre class="p">code</pre>', 'pre'), ('<a href="/">link</a>', 'a')]
['<pre class="p">code</pre>', '<a href="/">link</a>']
```

PS: Странно, что ты используешь `.+?` после тега. Я бы использовал `.*?`, а ещё лучше - `\b.*?`. Но при том, что ты вообще не делишь на тег и содержимое, можно ещё упростить и выкинуть `>.+?`. Я бы использовал `(<(pre|a)\b.+?</\2>)` (на этот раз `+` потому что там должен быть хотя бы `>`).